# Custom Binary Division?

Tags: c#, binary, integer-division

Hi I am trying to use the custom Binary Integer division method:
Source: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=642

```
public static void DivMod (Int128 dividend, Int128 divisor, out Int128 quotient, out  Int128 remainder)
{
// Determine the sign of the results and make the operands positive.
int remainderSign = 1;
int quotientSign = 1;
if (dividend < 0)
{
    dividend = -dividend;
    remainderSign = -1;
}
if (divisor < 0)
{
    divisor = -divisor;
    quotientSign = -1;
}
quotientSign *= remainderSign;

quotient = dividend;
remainder = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    // Left shift Remainder:Quotient by 1
    remainder <<= 1;
    if (quotient < 0)
        remainder._lo |= 1;
    quotient <<= 1;

    if (remainder >= divisor)
    {
        remainder -= divisor;
        quotient++;
    }
}

// Adjust sign of the results.
quotient *= quotientSign;
remainder *= remainderSign;
}
```

- However I have 2 problems:

**1) I would like to use it for 32 bit integers not Int128**. so I assume that the *Int128* should be replaced by *int*, and the (int i = 0; **i < 128**; i++) should be replaced by **i < 32;**. Correct?

**2) remainder._lo |= 1** -> this line does not work at all in C#. I suppose it has to do with that custom 128bit int struct they use, and I have no idea what it is meant to do. Can somebody help me out with this one, and translate it so that it works with int32?

**EDIT:** just to clarify I know what the bitwise operators do, the problem part is this:
**remainder._lo**. I dont know what this property refers to, and not sure of the purpose of this line, and how it would be translated to an int32?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work at all in C#"? Bit wise operators are alive and well... What do you see? Of you are using "int" instead of a custom struct, then indeed: no .lo will be defined, but...

Comment: yes the problem originates from the fact that they use an unavailable 128bit int struct which has a property of "_lo". Which the native 32bit int doesnt have, and I have no idea what is happening in that line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To use it with 32 bit integer (`System.Int32`) you can replace Int128 with int and the 128 in the for loop with 32 - So this is correct.
2. The `_lo` property is just the lower 64 bits of the 128 bits number. It is used because the biggest integer type in .NET is 64 bits (`System.Int64`) - So with 32 bits you can just omit the property:
   `remainder |= 1;`

If you follow the link you gave in your question and go back a few pages you will find the actual implementation of the `Int128` struct. It starts [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=636).

Comment: This is a very well written asnwer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is explained on [this page](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=637) of the guide:

```
public struct Int128 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<Int128_done>, IEquatable<Int128_done>

{
  private ulong _lo;
  private long _hi;

  public Int128(UInt64 low, Int64 high)
  {
    _lo = low;
    _hi = high;
  }
}
```

You can ignore it with 32 bit integers, and just do `some32int |= 1`.

He says to loop once for each bit, so with a 32 bit integer you would loop only 32 times.